# No me funciona el form de laravel 5.8 para registrar datos en base de datos

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
@extends('layouts.admin')
@section('contenido')

<div class="row">

<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <h3>Nueva Categoria</h3>

    @if (count($errors)>0) <!--indicamos si los errores al cargar el form son mayores que 0-->
        <!--enviamos un alerta-->
        <div class="alert alert-danger">

            <!--creamos un bucle que mostrara todos los errors que tengamos al momento de cargar el form-->

            <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{$error}}</li>
            @endforeach
            </ul>

        </div>
    @endif

    <!--abrimos el formulario de registro-->

<form method="post" action="{{ route('almacen/categoria') }}">
<!--{!!Form::Open(array(['route'=>'almacen/categoria','method'=>'$_POST','autocomplete'=>'off']))!!}
-->


<div class="form-group">
@csrf
<label for="nombre">Nombre Categoria</label>
<input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" placeholder=" ">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="nombre">Descripcion Categoria</label>
<input type="text" name="descripcion" class="form-control" placeholder=" ">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Guardar</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger" type="reset"> Cancelar</button>
</div>

<!--{!!Form::Close()!!}-->
</form>

</div>

</div>


@endsection
```

Al ejecutarlo me salta error y no me permite correr el formulario. Me tira error en varios lados, según dice unos de los errores que la ruta no esta definida. Siendo que revise y esta todo en regla.

Comment: Hola, podrías poner los errores que te sale? así te podemos ayudar mejor. Saludos

Comment: Sin conocer los errores es difícil dar una respuesta acertada.

Comment: Hola a todos, desde ya muchas gracias por su interes en ayudarme a solucionar el inconveniente. EL problema sucitaba en que no tenia creada la ruta post ni get. una vez que cree ambas rutas me funciona el codigo. Recien hoy lo solucione...

Answer (score 0):

Empezamos por el error de la ruta:

```
... action="{{ route('almacen/categoria') }}" ...
```

Tienes dos opciones de arreglarlo:

#1. Opción - Usar el helper [url()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-url)

```
... action="{{ url('almacen/categoria') }}" ...
```

#2. Opción - Crear o configurar correctamente la ruta [Named Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-url)

Para eso tienes que ir a tu archivo `routes/web.php` y darle un nombre a la ruta:

```
Route::post( 'almacen/categoria', 'XxxController@tu_método' )->name( 'almacen.categoria' );
```

y en el `<form>` lo puedes llamar con el helper `route()`:

```
... action="{{ route('almacen.categoria') }}" ...
```

Esto te debería solucionar en principio el problema de la ruta.

Comment: En web.php tengo la siguiente ruta declarada: Route::resource('/almacen/categoria','CategoriaController');

Comment: Pues pon la 2ª opción (`Route::post( 'almacen/categoria', ....` ) encima de tu `Route::resource('/almacen/categoria', ....` y luego lo llamas con `route('almacen.categoria')` ... te dejo más información sobre los [controladoes resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#resource-controllers) y [esto](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#restful-supplementing-resource-controllers)

Comment: el proceso sucita cuando realizo la llamada a la accion ya que he creado nuevamente todo el formulario y se muestra correctamente sin la llamada a la accion ...

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un error de concepto, $_POST contiene los datos que mandes por POST, por ejemplo $_POST['metodo'] o directamente puedes poner POST, GET, PUT(este es realmente un post), DELETE (este es realmente un post)

Por tanto

```
'method'=>'$_POST'
```

remplazalo por

```
'method'=>'post'
```

o bien

```
'method'=>'$_POST["metodo"]'
```

Comment: he tratado de las dos maneras y me sigue el error.. tengo entendido que laravelcollective no es aun compatible con laravel 5.8 por lo que me da ese error.. tambien trate de utilizar html y sige.. no entiendo que sucede aun!